# GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS) returns null when loading 3D model using Rajawali framework

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rajawali

I am trying to get my 3D model in my scene for the first time using:

> org.rajawali3d.loader.LoaderOBJ

I am unable to get it working. the app keeps crashing with the error below.
Digging in the code I found that the part that makes it crash is this line:

```
String extensions = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

extensions is null and the library doesn't check its validity.

onCreateView of my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mLayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.opengl_scene, container, false);
        mRenderSurface = (ISurface) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.opengl);
        mRenderer = new RocketArrowRenderer(getContext());
        applyRenderer();
        return mLayout;
    }
```

And the Renderer:

```
public class RocketArrowRenderer extends Renderer {
    private PointLight mLight;
    private Object3D mObjectGroup;
    private Animation3D mCameraAnim, mLightAnim;

    public RocketArrowRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFrameRate(60);
        initScene();
    }

    protected void initScene() {
        mLight = new PointLight();
        mLight.setPosition(0, 0, 4);
        mLight.setPower(3);
        getCurrentScene().addLight(mLight);
        getCurrentCamera().setZ(16);
        LoaderOBJ objParser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, R.raw.falcon_heavy_obj);
        try {
            objParser.parse();
            mObjectGroup = objParser.getParsedObject();
            getCurrentScene().addChild(mObjectGroup);

            mCameraAnim = new RotateOnAxisAnimation(Vector3.Axis.Y, 360);
            mCameraAnim.setDurationMilliseconds(8000);
            mCameraAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RepeatMode.INFINITE);
            mCameraAnim.setTransformable3D(mObjectGroup);
        } catch(ParsingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mLightAnim = new EllipticalOrbitAnimation3D(new Vector3(),
                new Vector3(0, 10, 0), Vector3.getAxisVector(Vector3.Axis.Z), 0,
                360, EllipticalOrbitAnimation3D.OrbitDirection.CLOCKWISE);

        mLightAnim.setDurationMilliseconds(3000);
        mLightAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RepeatMode.INFINITE);
        mLightAnim.setTransformable3D(mLight);

        getCurrentScene().registerAnimation(mCameraAnim);
        getCurrentScene().registerAnimation(mLightAnim);

        mCameraAnim.play();
        mLightAnim.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    }
}
```